# parse android disable multiple notifications

Tags: parse-platform, android-notifications, parse-android-sdk

(Parse 1.8.0 ANDROID)
How I disable multiple notifications?
For example , if I send two notifications then appear two icons in phone bar. I want to have only 1 icon.

Answer (score 0):

Create both notifications with the same id. This will force the second notification to update the first one, rather than creating another one.